# How to check if auth token is expired and force logout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am using auth0 for my client-side user authentication and authorization. This is the flow`

```
const authService = new auth0.WebAuth(coreConstants.AUTH0_OPTIONS);
const currentDate = Date.now();

authService.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
    if(err) console.log(err)
    const idToken = authResult.idToken;
    window.localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify({
                            expiresAt: someDate + Date.now()
                            accessToken: authResult.accessToken,
                            idToken,
                        }));
})
```

My problem now is that when the token is expired the user yet can interact with the page and just refreshing the page redirects the user to the login page. I have already read `auth0` documentation but couldn't find an appropriate solution for checking if the token is expired. Any bits of advice?

Comment: what condition are you checking on every page load?

Comment: I am checking if expireDate is less than currentDate and if not , user should pass auth flow again . But `authentication` fucntion runs only once in componentDidMount . I just think it's not good practice to call it in every route change

Comment: add full code. so i can check. Share router module name also

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [jwt.verify](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/README.md#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback) ? it will check if the token is expired.

Comment: I use express-jwt. Is it possible to check with that lib ?

Comment: I don' know exactly if it's possible, try it or you can use this package of express-jwt  –   [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt-verify).